# How to extract number of sentences before and after keyword by regex

Tags: java, regex

- My paragraph: *Hello. This is the start paragraph. There is another sentence. This sentence contains a **keyword** that can be matched. I need to take this sentence. And this sentence as well. This one is excluded.*
- My search keyword: **keyword**
- Expect result: *This is the start. There is another sentence. This sentence contains a keyword that can be matched. I need to take this sentence. And this sentence as well*

I'd like to get the a number of sentences before & after the keyword in paragraph (and also include the sentence that contains keyword. 
In above example, the number of sentences is 2, if there is not enough sentences, then return maximum that it can get (1 or 0).

I tried with this pattern `"\.([^.]+\.[^.]*" + "keyword" + "[^.]*\.[^.]+)"` to get sentences with dot but I can't control the number of sentences. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you split on the keyword and then count the sentence delimiters in each chunk?

Comment: You are correct that my answer was wrong. I misunderstood the question, but that was not your fault. The question is clear. I therefore deleted my answer. If I can fix it I will do so, but It will be a few hours before I can attend to that. Actually, I do have one question: can `keyword` appear more than once in the text, and if so what is to be returned when it appears more than once?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it can appear more than once, but I just need to focus on the first match & ignore the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really, really close! First, you really don't need that initial period, or else it will refrain from matching the first sentence in a paragraph (despite whether or not it should be matched based on the number of sentences).

To answer your main question, simply varying the number of [^.]*\. worked great for me. To do this easily within regex, you can use a [Quantifier] with the syntax `(group){number}` or `(group){min,max}` to match the previous group a specific number of times. Adding this to your initial regex:
`"(([^.]*\.){2}[^.]*" + "keyword" + "[^.]*\.([^.]*\.){3})"` for 2 before, 3 after, or 
`"(([^.]*\.){" + before + "}[^.]*" + "keyword" + "[^.]*\.([^.]*\.){" + after + "})` for the programmable version.

Comment: Good answer. Two small suggested changes: 1) you don't need to put the match in a capture group as it is only the match itself that is of interest. 2) you are using the other two capture groups as non-capture groups. That's fine, except readers may assume you used capture groups to reference their contents later, only to find that is not the case, something that would not happen if they were non-capture groups. I therefore suggest `(?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*keyword[^.]*\.(?:[^.]*\.){3}`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Wd9gK/1/). I suggest also that you always link to an on-line regex tester.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this pattern `"\\.?([^.]+\\.[^.]*){0,2}" + "keyword[^.]*\\." + "([^.]+\\.){0,2}"` can solve your problem.